# Generating points according to constraints matrix

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I am trying to build a model of points in the space, where each point has constraints with other points (which means that if point a and b has a constraint of 5, then the distance between them must be exactly 5).

[image: Here]

is a basic model, where the green is the nodes, and the red are the constraints.

I need to find the `x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3.`

The model receive a matrix of constraints.

In the case of the model above, the matrix will be:

```
[[0, 4 -1]
[ 4, 0, 5],
[-1, 5, 0]]
```

now, when the model is easy, This is an easy task.
But when adding more constrains, like this model,

[image: this]

that will get the matrix :

```
[[0, 4 -1,  4]
[ 4, 0, 5, -1],
[-1, 5, 0,  5],
[4, -1, 5,  0]]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to create this model when the input is a matrix of constraints?

Comment: In general this is a [difficult problem](https://core.ac.uk/reader/82223497), that doesn't mean that it *can't* be done of course. It's also possible to approximate using a networks of springs that each have a preferred length and iterative solving to minimize the energy. What sort of solution are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I am providing the data for the models, so I can assume that there is a solution. so I need the solution to have 0 error (all the points are in the exact distant as as the constrain).